# runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference (2)

Tags: go

I am new in **Go** and need help!

In PostgreSQL database I have table called `factors`. This table has 2 column (`factor_id` and `factor_name`). Right now I am successfully connected to PostgreSQL database from Go application.

When I am tring to make query based GET request in console I see error.

```
http://localhost:8000/api/factors/?limit=5&offset=1
```

Where I make mistake? Please help me to fix the problem.

**controllers/factors.go**:

```
package controllers

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "restify/models"
    "restify/utils"
)

var GetFactors = func(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    data := models.Factors{}

    err := models.GetFactors(&data, req.URL.Query().Get("limit"), req.URL.Query().Get("offset"))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        http.Error(res, err.Error(), 500)
        return
    }

    out, err := json.Marshal(data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        http.Error(res, err.Error(), 501)
        return
    }

    resp := make(map[string]interface{})

    resp["Dictionaries"] = string(out)

    utils.Respond(res, resp)

}
```

**models/factors.go**:

```
package models

import (
    "fmt"
    "restify/database"
)

type Factor struct {
    FactorID int `json:"factor_id"`
    FactorName string `json:"factor_name"`
}

type Factors struct {
    Array[]Factor
}

func GetFactors(data *Factors, limit string, offset string) error {
    rows, err := database.DB.Query(`SELECT * FROM factors ORDER BY factor_id LIMIT ` + limit + ` OFFSET ` + offset + `;`)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return err
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {
        var id int
        var name string
        model := Factor{}
        err = rows.Scan(&id, &name)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return err
        }
        model.FactorID = id
        model.FactorName = name
        data.Array = append(data.Array, model)
    }
    err = rows.Err()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

**ERROR:**

```
2019/02/26 16:25:55 http: panic serving [::1]:20932: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 11 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc0002badc0)
    C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:1746 +0xd7
panic(0x6dad20, 0x970890)
    C:/Go/src/runtime/panic.go:513 +0x1c7
database/sql.(*DB).conn(0x0, 0x78a500, 0xc0000100a8, 0x10000c000339801, 0x0, 0xc000339898, 0xc000339830)
    C:/Go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1081 +0x41
database/sql.(*DB).query(0x0, 0x78a500, 0xc0000100a8, 0xc000356040, 0x3a, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc000356001, 0x3a, ...)
    C:/Go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1514 +0x6d
database/sql.(*DB).QueryContext(0x0, 0x78a500, 0xc0000100a8, 0xc000356040, 0x3a, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x5, 0xc000356040, ...)
    C:/Go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1496 +0xda
database/sql.(*DB).Query(0x0, 0xc000356040, 0x3a, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x8, 0xc00034e016, 0x1)
    C:/Go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1510 +0x89
restify/models.GetFactors(0xc000339b28, 0xc00034e016, 0x1, 0xc00034e01e, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
    C:/Users/NNogerbek/go/src/restify/models/factors.go:18 +0xf6
restify/controllers.glob..func1(0x78a2c0, 0xc00035a000, 0xc000332200)
    C:/Users/NNogerbek/go/src/restify/controllers/factors.go:14 +0xd3
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x74da58, 0x78a2c0, 0xc00035a000, 0xc000332200)
    C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:1964 +0x4b
github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP(0xc0002fc180, 0x78a2c0, 0xc00035a000, 0xc000310300)
    C:/Users/NNogerbek/go/src/github.com/gorilla/mux/mux.go:212 +0xd7
github.com/gorilla/handlers.(*cors).ServeHTTP(0xc0001f2120, 0x78a2c0, 0xc00035a000, 0xc000310300)
    C:/Users/NNogerbek/go/src/github.com/gorilla/handlers/cors.go:54 +0xa95
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc000056b60, 0x78a2c0, 0xc00035a000, 0xc000310300)
    C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:2741 +0xb2
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc0002badc0, 0x78a4c0, 0xc000340040)
    C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:1847 +0x64d
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:2851 +0x2fc
```

**database/database.go**:

```
package database

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "log"
    "restify/utils"
)

var DB *sql.DB

/*
Function: "Connect".

Description:
The main task of the function is to initialize database connection.
*/
func Open() () {
    // Load environment variables from ".env" file.
    err := godotenv.Load(".env")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Initialize database related variables.
    dbUser := utils.CheckEnvironmentVariable("PostgreSQL_USER")
    dbPassword := utils.CheckEnvironmentVariable("PostgreSQL_PASSWORD")
    dbHost := utils.CheckEnvironmentVariable("PostgreSQL_HOST")
    dbName := utils.CheckEnvironmentVariable("PostgreSQL_DATABASE_NAME")

    // Defining connection string for PostgreSQL database.
    dbURL := fmt.Sprintf("user=%s password=%s host=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable", dbUser, dbPassword, dbHost, dbName)

    // Create PostgreSQL database connection pool.
    DB, err := sql.Open("postgres", dbURL)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Ping PostgreSQL database to make sure it's alive.
    err = DB.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    log.Println("REST API web service successfully connected to remote PostgreSQL database.")
}

/*
Function: "Disconnect"

Description:
The main task of the function is to disconnect database connection.
*/
func Close() error {
    return DB.Close()
}
```

Comment: how are you initialising the DB?
What is restify/database pkg?

Comment: It seems to be that `database.DB` is not initialized.

Comment: @SauravPrakash hello! Can you check my post again please?! I add code of restify/database pkg. It's not third-party pkg. Do you have any ideas now?

Comment: @JamilloSantos I am successfully connected to PostgreSQL database. In `main.go` file I use such code `database.Open()` and after that I use `defer database.Close()`. It show me successfull message. Can you check my post again please?! I add code of `restify/database pkg`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the problem is when DB is assigned here:

```
DB, err := sql.Open("postgres", dbURL)
```

The DB gets defined in a new scope and hence this creates a local variable rather than setting the pkg level variable.
Hence the code `Open()` establishes a connection to DB.

Try with this:

```
var err error
DB, err = sql.Open("postgres", dbURL)
```

Here is the official quote:

> Unlike regular variable declarations, a short variable declaration may redeclare variables provided they were originally declared earlier in the same block (or the parameter lists if the block is the function body) with the same type, and at least one of the non-blank variables is new. As a consequence, redeclaration can only appear in a multi-variable short declaration. Redeclaration does not introduce a new variable; it just assigns a new value to the original.

Comment: Thank you! :) In my case I changed `:=` symbol to `=` as you adviced. In the same time I removed `var err error` code cause it was unnecessary. Now it works.